# Declaring a variable in TSQL using CAST and GETUTCDATE() ... What is the most efficient way?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, declare, getdate

If I use:

```
declare @CurrentDate as date = cast(getutcdate() at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'Pacific Standard Time' as date)
```

Is the CAST performed every time I call the variable, or just in the initial declare statement?

Comment: cast occurs at initialization.  currentdate is of date type.  the variable does not transform data, it only can be assigned data.  build a function to transform string data to universal time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getutcdate()` and the surrounding `cast()` are only called when you first assign to the `@CurrentDate` variable. Variables are *values*, not functions. You create the variable with a certain type, and assign a specific value of that type to it.

However, the **type** of the `@CurrentVariable` is `Date`... not `DateTime`. Not `DateTime2`. Not `DateTimeOffset`. This means the variable only holds the `Date` information. There is no time component, and so, for today, the `2019-03-29` value assigned will continue to be valid all day.

Very soon now the UTC date will become `2019-03-30`. This will happen in England (or somewhere with a positive UTC offset) long before it happens anywhere in the US. Even so, the value in the variable will stay `2019-30-29`.

What gets really confusing is when you assign the variable in a location where the date value is different from local time, and the transition happens while the program is still running. The value in the variable *never changes*, unless you assign to it again... but the expectation of the meaning of that value does change.

Comment: This is what I assumed but wanted to check.  Thanks for the fast response.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Having the value stay the same doesnt concern me too much for what I am using it for.  It is just being used in a quick query that is run in the middle of the day.